# how move an image on mainview

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, move, scale, crop

i've got a problem with iPhone SDK.
I want create an imageView that user can touch and move and scale as he wish.

How can i do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easy way is to put it in a UIScrollView and enable the methods of the UIScrollViewDelegate that you wan't to use (scrool / zoom)

take a look at the apple sample project "PhotoScroller", you can find it in xCode help...

ciao,
luca

Answer (score 1):

Look at UIGestureRecognizer : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Especially, UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Answer (score 1):

for moving an object, you can CGAfflineTransformation to move from x axis to y axis.

u write up those code in Touch Delegates. also set the UIImage frame as CGRectZero.

```
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:.50];
    titl.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(260, 0);
    comment.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, 100); 
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

this is the code to move an object from one place to another. this might help you

Answer (score 1):

```
 - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
         [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
         CGPoint touchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:[self window]];
         float deltaX = touchPoint.x - lastUpdatedPoint.x;
         float deltaY = touchPoint.y - lastUpdatedPoint.y;
         float newCenterX = [[self layer] position].x + deltaX; float newCenterY = [[self layer] position].y + deltaY;
         CGPoint center = CGPointMake(newCenterX, newCenterY);
         [[self layer] setPosition:center]; 
         lastUpdatedPoint = touchPoint;
         [UIView commitAnimations];
       }
```

BY 
CNSivakumar